# Rendering different image formats in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

In my Django project, I have a template where I have to upload an image corresponding to the the dynamic instance. For eg: Corresponding to a Student model, I have a template so that I can serve each student's info(including profile photo) on a unique url i.e. `/student/student_X`. Now for some students, I have a .jpg image while for others a .png image. Currently I have just hardcoded the template so as to handle only the .jpg images in the following way.

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}students/images/{{ student.slug }}.jpg">
```

where `student` is the context passed to the template.

How can I modify this so that if a particular student does not have .jpg image available, .png is served? What if there is a set of multiple image formats?

Answer (score 0):

Read this before going further, as understanding media/static files and their differences is very important in Django.
http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/06/25/django-and-static-files/

As it is, your method could be greatly simplified. If using a Django [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) in your model the location of the file is stored in your db and there is NO need to differentiate between image types.

Without knowing how you are storing these files and calling students in the view there's no further way to help, but if you are calling field from a Student model object, you can pass the whole Student to the context variables and call the slug like this-

Media files in Django are files uploaded to a location specified in settings.py, of which the location is stored in the db for easy retrieval.